# Having a table in an enumerate environment

Tags: tables, floats, lists

I have a problem trying to add a table in an `enumerate` environment in LaTeX.

I want the table to act as if it were just another piece of text. i.e. showing up exactly right next to the `\item` in an `enumerate` environment.

I currently use this to create my table (`M` is to have a 'math' table):

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[i.]
  \item
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{M M|M M M M M M M}
        \hline
        p & q & (p & \rightarrow & q) & \rightarrow & (q & \rightarrow & p) \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & ~ & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ \\ 
        0 & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ & 0 & ~ & 0 & ~ \\
        1 & 0 & ~ & 0 & ~ & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ \\  
        1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ & 1 & ~ \\ 
        \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & \uparrow & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

But when the code is compiled the table shows up outside of the enumeration.

Comment: Check your documentation: You don't need the `table` environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `table` environment is merely a placeholder for a float using the `table` counter. However, it can contain anything - not necessarilty a `tabular` (even an image is fine, really). In this instance though, you don't need to let the `tabular` float, so you should use it as-is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[i.]
  \item
    \begin{tabular}{M M|M M M}
        \hline
        p & q & (p \rightarrow q) & \rightarrow & (q \rightarrow p) \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\  
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        \hline
         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \uparrow & \\ 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

You don't really need the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) here, since you can post the entire `tabular` as a `$\begin{array}{cc|ccc}...\end{array}$` and obtain the same result.

Other packages you might consider include [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumite) for list management and [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for publishing-quality table constructions. Here's a take using the above suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.]
  \item
    $\begin{array}{c c c c c}
        \toprule
        p & q & (p \rightarrow q) & \rightarrow & (q \rightarrow p) \\ \midrule
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\  
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        \bottomrule
         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \uparrow &
    \end{array}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

Vertical alignment is also adjustable using a `[t]` or `[b]` optional argument to either `tabular` or `array`. This would align the structure to either the `t`op or the `b`ottom line/row.